# Specialize template function to return vector

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Let's say I have a reader class over a file:

```
class Reader {
public:
    template <class T>
    T Read();
};
```

Its only function is the `Read` function that reads any arithmetic type (`static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)`) from a file. Now I want to create a specialization of that function, which reads a vector from the file. How would I go about doing that with templates? Something like the following doesn't work:

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T> Read<std::vector<T>>();
```

```
error: function template partial specialization is not allowed
std::vector<U> Read<std::vector<U>>();
               ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't partially specialize functions. You can overload them though, but the way of doing it is not obvious, since your function doesn't take any parameters.

First, you need a way to check if a type is a `std::vector<??>`:

```
template <typename T> struct IsVector : std::false_type {};
template <typename ...P> struct IsVector<std::vector<P...>> : std::true_type {};
```

Then you can plug it into `requires`:

```
template <typename T>
T Read()
{
    // Generic overload
}

template <typename T> requires IsVector<T>::value
T Read()
{
    // Vector overload
}
```

Alternatively, you could have a single function, with `if constexpr (IsVector<T>::value)` inside.

Answer (score 0):

A way to implement what you want is to delegate the logic of your member function to a couple of private member functions:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

class BinaryReader {
   public:
    template <class T>
    T Read() {
        T t{};
        this->ReadImpl(t);
        return t;
    }

private:
    template <class T>
    void ReadImpl(T& t) {
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>);
        std::puts("T");
        t = T{}; // implement your logic here
    }

    template <class T>
    void ReadImpl(std::vector<T>& t) {
        std::puts("std::vector<T>");
        t = std::vector<T>{}; // implement your logic here
    }
};

int main() {
    BinaryReader br;
    br.Read<int>();
    br.Read<std::vector<int>>();
}
```

This doesn't require you to introduce new type traits to check if your type is a `std::vector<>`. However, it requires your return types to be default constructible.

Output:

```
T
std::vector<T>
```